# How does the last() SQL function work?

Tags: php, mysql

this is how i am attempting to use it:

```
<?php
$post_title_edited=$post1 . "vs" . $post2;

$con2=mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name2")or die("cannot select DB");


// Create table
$create = 'CREATE TABLE  '. $post_title_edited .' 
(
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
  user VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
  user_post VARCHAR(2000) NOT NULL, 
  date VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
)';



// Execute query
mysql_query($create,$con2);

echo $post_title_edited;



$query='SELECT LAST(id) as LastId FROM '.$post_title_edited.'';
$last=mysql_query($query);

echo $last;
?>
```

post1 and post2 are user inputs. the table is created and the first echo works. the second one does not. i suppose this may be a mad place to test this code as the table is empty, put i have tested it on a similar table with 5 entries and have gotten the same result,nothing. from the little i have been able to scoop up on google, im using it correctly. i even resorted to using bing on this one just in case google missed something. i cant seem to find a solid explanation of how to use this. thanks in advance.

regardless of the code, i would really just like an explanation of how last() or first() works, i've seen bits of other ways to find the first or last value of an sql column. but again those were explained rather poorly

Comment: What you are trying to do here?

Comment: i think he wants last_insert_id()

Comment: @guido might be. But before inserting anything. So you'd call it max auto_increment?

Comment: thats why he talks about *"... this may be a mad place to test this code as the table is empty, put i have tested it on a similar table with 5 entries and have gotten the same result..."*.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im nope, it's not a max; it the last auto_increment id inserted in current session

Comment: There is no `last()` function in MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not `ORDER` and `LIMIT`:

```
$query='SELECT id as LastId FROM '.$post_title_edited.' ORDER BY LastId DESC LIMIT 1';
```

Comment: this looks like sql server not mysql

Comment: `TOP` is not available in *mysql*

Comment: My first answer was exactly like this. Then I saw `sql` tag and change it to sql

Comment: **SQL** does not (automatically) mean *Microsoft SQL Server*. `SQL` is a query language for relational databases. It is ***not*** a DBMS product.

Comment: I just assumed, anyway, my original post was for mysql, then changed, and changed back.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `LAST()` function in mysql.

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=2020

And if you want last record the query is posted by Mihai Lorga use it.

Comment: @MihaiIorga look the post carefully...  `$con2=mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name2")or die("cannot select DB");
` this is what he has added..

Comment: @MihaiIorga he wants **mysql** not mssql

Comment: I saw tag SQL and I assumed he wants SQL